# razor view a lone and inside another razor view, what is the best practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently working on an ASP.Net MVC project and i'm using razor views.
I've a controller's action; say action A which has its own razor view; say view A.

Also, i have another controller's action; action B, and has its own razor view; view B.

Now, i want to have the razor view A inside the razor view B; instead of copying all the view A contents in view B to avoid repeated code.

What do you suggest?

any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at using partial views (using `@Html.Partial()` or `@Html.Action()`) for content that is repeated across multiple views.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `B.cshtml` call

```
@Html.Partial("A.cshtml", modelForA)
```

Comment: Thanks james for your reply, but i have Model A for view A, and another model B which includes Model A inside it. what shall the shared view's model will be then?

Comment: @MarwaAhmad `modelB.modelA`

Comment: James, then the shared view model will be : **@ model ModelA** or **@ model ModelB**  P.S: if i passed ModelA then when i post the data to the action B then Model B data will not exist! i should send the whole parent i.e. Model B. if i make the shared's view is ModelB, then the ActionA should send extra data to that shared view not only ModelA. got me?

Comment: @MarwaAhmad i'm not sure why you find this confusing. The model for `A.cshtml` stays as `ModelA` and the model for `B.cshtml` stays as `ModelB`, *inside* `B.cshtml` you would pass `ModelA` (as you said `ModelB` includes `ModelA`) down into the partial method.

Answer (score 1):

if there is no model to pass then Inside `B.cshtml` call (do not need .cshtml)

```
@Html.Partial("A")
```

with model

```
@Html.Partial("A", @Model.SubModel)
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj for your reply, but i have two different models.

Comment: Where did you get those models from. parent model? then just pass whole parent model

Comment: Yes Manoj, then the shared view model will be :

@ model ModelA
or
@ model ModelB 


    P.S:

if i passed ModelA then when i post the data to the action B then Model B data will not exist! i should send the whole parent i.e. Model B. 
  
if i make the shared's view is ModelB, then the ActionA should send extra data to that shared view not only ModelA.   
got me?

Comment: Sounds like you need a wrapper model that will hold multiple models, then you can just work with single model to overcome these problems.